# Yocto QML Touchscreen

Tags: qt, qml, touchscreen, yocto

I use Elo touchscreen for my project with Yocto. To calibrate it I use `ts_calibrate` with the following options:

```
export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event0
export TSLIB_CALIBFILE=/etc/pointercal
export TSLIB_CONFFILE=/etc/ts.conf
```

Afterwards I execute `ts_test` to verify the calibration outcome. So far so good, `ts_test` does not highlight any problem.

However when I run my QML application the touchscreen acts as not calibrated at all. I can control the mouse via touchscreen but the mouse pointer is not underneath my finger. Also, on each tap on the screen, the mouse pointer goes to totally different and random areas.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I have a similar use case. I have a Nitrogen6x board that is running Yocto 2.1 with Qt 5.6.0 and I have connected a Elo touchscreen monitor to the Nitrogen board using HDMI to VGA converter cable. My Qt application is running fine on the monitor but the monitor was not detected as touch screen monitor, and I dont see any /dev/input/* device mapped for the touchscreen input. How did you get your touchscreen to be detected and respond to touch on Yocto/Qt environment. Any help on this is really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: i use my monitor by hdmi - vga converter but my monitor have a usb input for touchscreen too. Did you connect USB cable to your board ?

Comment: Yes. I have enabled HID Support under Kernel configuration and the touchscreen started working. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by add qt5-env.sh file following lines:

```
export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event0
export TSLIB_CALIBFILE=/etc/pointercal
export TSLIB_CONFFILE=/etc/ts.conf
export QT_QPA_EVDEV_TOUCHSCREEN_PARAMETERS=/dev/input/event0
export QT_QPA_FB_TSLIB=1
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_HIDECURSOR=1
export QT_QPA_EVDEV_MOUSE_PARAMETERS=abs
```